# Ho to use devel on commerce_cart_order_refresh or similar

Tags: debugging

I want to implement the solution on this link [Alter cart unit price and total amount](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/alter-cart-unit-price-and-total-amount). I want to use dpm on devel to look for available fields on line items but I doesnt show on.

Code that I used: 
function mymodule_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper) {
   dpm($order_wrapper);
}

function mymodule_calculate_product_price_cart($order) {
    dpm($order);
 }

Both of these doesnt show the devel on the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that Commerce cart context is loading in the particular page you wanted to dpm/dsm for function hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper) &
2. And where you declared this **function mymodule_calculate_product_price_cart($order) { dpm($order); }** can you brief this for more clarity.

Comment: Basically I want to alter the total price amount after adding the product to cart or maybe when they visit the checkout page since I have a redirect to checkout after adding product to cart.

Comment: Hi, For altering the price based on users/ or on different condition. One way using Rules module and try to write a class based on commerce_price/resolver. Here is the reference it will definitely help you, pls follow this: [modify product price](https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/modifying-product-prices-drupal-commerce-2-drupal-8).